# Python searching for largest digit in a string of letters and numbers

Tags: python, parsing, if-statement, typeerror

This is a function that takes in a very long string and searches for any numbers in it and returns the largest. I keep getting `TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()`

```
def largest_digit(s):

  largest = 0
  if len(s) == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    for x in range(len(s)):
      if s[x].isdigit() and if int(s[x]) > largest:
        largest = s[x]
  return largest`
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "1.py", line 36, in main
    x = largest_digit(s)
  File "1.py", line 14, in largest_digit
    if int(s[x]) > largest:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong - `largest` is a string.

Comment: **if** s[x].isdigit() and **if** int(s[x]) > largest:  Two `if` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `largest` is assigned, it references a string object. The following predicate compares `int` and `str` which is not possible in Python 3.x (fortunately). (In Python 2 you'd just silently get the wrong answer by comparing them.)

```
int(s[x]) > largest
```

---

Replace:

```
    largest = s[x]
```

with:

```
    largest = int(s[x])
```

OR

Replace:

```
  if s[x].isdigit() and int(s[x]) > largest:
```

with:

```
  if s[x].isdigit() and int(s[x]) > int(largest):
```

to get a proper result (not to avoid error).

BTW, you don't need the outer `if` because iterating an empty sequence is okay.

Comment: (In Python 2 you'd just silently get the wrong answer by comparing them...)

Comment: @Wooble, Thank you for the comment. I included your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
strName = "This5 contai3ns numb9rs"
largest = 0
if len(strName) == 0:
  print "Its empty"
else:
  for x in range(len(strName)):
    if strName[x].isdigit() and int(strName[x]) > largest:
      largest = ***NOTE THIS*** int(strName[x])
  print largest
```

You need to give largest an int value not a string.
Also you need to lose the 2nd if here:

```
if s[x].isdigit() and if int(s[x]) > largest:
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the problem would be to use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "234fflr  lglrlk5674 fglh0335kdkgel"
>>> m = re.findall("\d", s) #look for all digits in the string and make list of them
>>> max(m)
'7'
```